# Swapping domains on a Magento install

Tags: magento-1.9, url, multidomain

I multi-store 1.9.1 with three current stores.  I have Site-A.com, Site-B.com, Site-C.com, running  its on a Godaddy VPS.  I own the url Site-D.com also, which redirects to Site-C.com.  So that's A, B, C running stores, with domain name D pointing back to C

I want to swap out the domain name Site-C.com  with Site-D.com.  Just a pure and simple swap.  I can add a fourth store view in Mage, but am wondering if just changing the URLs in the System>Config would be easier.

How exactly should I handle the files on the server?  Just tell any traffic visiting Site-A.com to mask the domain to show the Site-B.com url, or should I add a new store view and that is all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, does site "D" redirect to site "C" or is the domain "parked" on top of site "C"?   If it redirects, then you'll need to work with the DNS a bit.  If it is parked on top of or otherwise shares the same server space (although Magento may redirect you to the other domain) then you should be able to just swap the configuration urls.

Make sure, with your current setup, that you can install SSL on the site "D" domain.  Some parked/redirected hosting setups won't allow it.

It's always a good idea to have a staging/dev server to test things like this on and not be playing with a live website unless you don't value it being highly available.

Comment: D is just a URL redir right now; I have added a new store view for it.  But currently on the server URL D just points to URL C.  Getting SSL now.  I use staging servers but this site doesn't require it.

Comment: I see that DNS is still pointing to a GoDaddy parking page.  Do I just need to change the a name IP address to that of the main store?

Comment: It all really depends on your server setup.   I would recommend talking to your hosting provider about how to reconfigure that domain to not be "parked".  Changing the A record to the ip of your store may not work if your server is not setup properly to serve that domain.